# ORACLE SQL: unable to left join 3 tables

Tags: oracle

How do I join 3 tables with left outer join? I was able to do left outer join between table1 and table2, but not table3.

I tried the following, but don't know how to join with table3.

```
select tab1.id, tab2.status, tab3.job_history 
from table1 tab1 
left outer join table2 tab2 on tab1.id=tab2.id 
where tab1.job_title='accounting'
```

My table schemas are:

```
table 1: 
  id           number(5) primary key,
  status_code  number(5),
  job_title    varchar2(20)
  name         varchar2(30)


table 2:
   status_code  number(5) primary key,
   status       varchar2(15)

table 3:
  id           number(5)
  job_history  varchar2(20)
```

Conditions:

- `table1.status_code` can be `null`
- `table1.id` may be not have any match for `table3.id`

I want to find the record in table1 that has `table1.job_title = 'accounting'` or in table3 has `table3.job_history = 'accounting'` when `table1.id = table3.id` and also get the table2 status with `table1.status_code = table2.status_code`

Comment: The schemas you show have not `table 2 id`, so what are you trying to perform your `left outer join` on? (Your SQL shows `table2 tab2 on tab1.id = tab2.id`, but there is no table2 ID column.)

Comment: Is the relationship between table 1 and table 3 a one to many?

Answer (score 0):

Since you have not same fields on all tables, to match your conditions, you probably will find easier way to run join like:

```
 select 
      tab1.id, 
      tab2.status, 
      tab3.job_history 
    from 
      table1 tab1,    
      table2 tab2,
      table3 tab3
    where 
      tab1.job_title='accounting'
      --ADD ADITIONAL FILTERING HERE
```

Query with join on 3 tables is look like this:

```
select 
  tab1.id, 
  tab2.status, 
  tab3.job_history 
from 
  table1 tab1 
left outer join 
  table2 tab2 on tab1.id=tab2.id 
left outer join  
   table3 tab3 on tab3.id = tab1.id
where 
  tab1.job_title='accounting'
```

Comment: This won't work. You missed the fact there is no `ID` column in `table2`.

Answer (score 0):

This SQL assumes that there is a one-to-one relationship between table 1, table 2 and table 3

```
select tab1.id, tab2.status, tab3.job_history 
from table1 tab1 
left outer join table2 tab2 on tab2.status_code = tab1.status_code 
left outer join table3 tab3 on tab3.id = tab1.id 
where tab1.job_title = 'accounting' or tab3.job_history = 'accounting'
```

Table 3 looks like it contains some form of job history, so it is likely there is going to more than one record in Table 3 for each record on Table 1. If this is the case you will need to perform a sub-query to find all people that currently or previously have a job title of accounting, i.e.

```
select tab1.id, tab2.status, tab1.job_title 
from table1 tab1 
left outer join table2 tab2 on tab2.status_code = tab1.status_code 
where tab1.job_title = 'accounting' or 
      tab1.id in (select id from tab3 where job_history = 'accounting')
```

Comment: This won't work. You missed the fact there is no `ID` column in `table2`.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you're wanting to join `table2` to `table1` on `status_code` instead of `id`, as there *is no* ID column in `table2`. To join the third table, just add another `LEFT OUTER JOIN` (or any other `JOIN`).

```
select 
  tab1.id, 
  tab2.status, 
  tab3.job_history 
from 
  table1 tab1 
left outer join 
  table2 tab2 on tab2.status_code = tab1.status_code
left outer join
  table3 tab3 on tab3.id = tab1.id 
where 
  tab1.job_title='accounting' or tab3.job_history = 'accounting'
```